# Check if a finger is placed on fingerprint sensor or not- Android

Tags: android, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api

I'm looking for a way to detect (something like a fired event) if the finger is placed on fingerprint sensor on Android devices. **I'm not looking for authentication** using fingerprint sensor, I just need to check if the fingerprint sensor responds to a placed finger or not.

Appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: [FingerprintManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only access the fingerprint sensor through the fingerprint authentication service. You would be able to tell if a fingerprint is on the sensor based on the response from the API of a success OR a failure, that would indicate that a finger is on the sensor either way.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, for fingerprint authentication to work you first need to enroll fingerprint and also have security enabled on the device. I was looking for something simple in which the user just need to place the finger and sensor will detect it.

Comment: As I said above, the only way to access a fingerprint sensor is through the authentication API.